# GWT: celltable column header's tooltip not appearing correctly

Tags: gwt

I am using a tool tip for GWT celltable column headers .

The problem is i can only see the first work of my tooltip and not the second word after space, for example if in the tool tip i write "hello world"

it appears as "hello"

the word after space not appearing ..

thats the code i am using

```
       cellTable.addColumn(myColumn, SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<span title="+"heloo world"+">"+Constants.XVD+"</span>"));
```

so in this case the tool tip says"heloo"  instead of "hello world"

as you can see in the attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
"<span title=\"heloo world\">"+Constants.XVD+"</span>"
```

will work ? (Escaping the ")